# Modal ajax rastreamento correios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-service

É possível fazer um script que puxe o rastreamento de algum item na página dos correios? Por exemplo, dentro do meu site: https://meusite.com.br/pedidos. Ai tem o link no caso pra rastreamento [PO117284423BR](http://teste)

Teria como criar um modal que quando o link "PO117284423BR" for clicado ele abrir com isso: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou algo parecido. É possivel? Ou com o site dos correios nao tem como?

Comment: a documentação do WS dos correios é https://www.correios.com.br/para-voce/correios-de-a-a-z/pdf/rastreamento-de-objetos/manual_rastreamentoobjetosws.pdf

Comment: Use o site http://linktrack.mooo.com/ ou faça simplemente http://linktrack.mooo.com/RX704890085CN/html. Ele é bem rápido e faz a consulta direto no site dos correios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infelizmente você não conseguirá utilizar diretamente o site dos correios.

Você precisará desenvolver uma aplicação, que usando a API dos correios (manual postado pelo Felipe), faça uma requisição para o site dos correios e retorne com as informações do rastreamento, e então você poderá montar uma página para exibir o resultado.

Pelo que li na página 11 do manual, você precisará solicitar um usuário e senha para poder utilizar o WS do correio e fazer essa requisição.

Uma alternativa, seria usar um outro site que faça todo esse trabalho para você.
Encontrei esse aqui:
http://www.linkcorreios.com.br

Parece que basta adicionar o código de rastreamento ao final da URL e pronto:
http://www.linkcorreios.com.br/?id=PO117284423BR

Você pode colocar esse link no seu site, e fazer ele abrir em uma modal ou em uma outra janela.

Comment: Por exemplo, tem como abrir com Ajax, somente tal DIV? Sem ser puxar tudo.

Comment: Apenas via JS não é possível, pois é uma restrição de segurança do navegador que você não possa manipular o HTML de outro domínio.

Comment: O que você poderia fazer é fazer a requisição dessa URL no servidor, usando alguma linguagem de programação como PHP por exemplo, e então interpretar a resposta e extrair apenas as informações que você deseja.

Answer (score 0):

O seguinte código HTML obtém esses dados de rastreamento:

```
<html>
<body onload="document.aux.submit()">

 <form name="aux" method="POST" action="https://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado_semcontent.cfm">
  <input name="Objetos" value="PO117284423BR">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

#### Uma dica:

Se quiser visualizar dados de rastreamento rapidamente no terminal, use o `curl` para enviar a solicitação à página dos correios, e um navegador em modo texto para visualizar a situação do pedido, como `html2text`, `elinks`, `lynx` ou `w3m`. Por exemplo, usando o `bash` no terminal do `Ubuntu`:

```
sudo apt install html2text
curl -sS -X POST -d Objetos=PO117284423BR https://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado_semcontent.cfm | html2text
```

ou

```
sudo apt install elinks 
curl -sS -X POST -d Objetos=PO117284423BR https://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado_semcontent.cfm | elinks -dump -dump-color-mode 1
```

ou

```
sudo apt install lynx    
curl -sS -X POST -d Objetos=PO117284423BR https://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado_semcontent.cfm | lynx --stdin --dump
```

ou

```
sudo apt install w3m    
curl -sS -X POST -d Objetos=PO117284423BR https://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/resultado_semcontent.cfm | w3m -dump -T text/html
```